# Pi camera: mmal:No data received from sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi

This question has been asked before but the solution did not solve my problem.

When I connect my Pi camera to my Raspberry Pi and use the command: `raspistill -o image.jpg`.

This gives an error:

> mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board.

All the connections are fine. I tried with two Pi cameras on two different Raspberry Pis but it still gives the same error. When I use the `raspistill` command then the red light of the camera goes on and I have also enabled camera on Pi via `sudo raspi-config`.

Please help.

Comment: I guess this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24460/how-to-write-raspistill-image-to-usb-drive was the link that didnt solve your problem? It didnt help me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this issue too.  I don't know if static electricity hurt the unit or if it happened in shipping.  I've seen several behaviors to the 5MP version I purchased.
First was putting it in the wrong port. Depending on your model you may just have it in the wrong port.  Some people have claimed putting in the other port may fry the camera.  I cannot confirm or deny that happens.

I similarly would run this command and get messages like:

`mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates`

Or the message you received.

I attempted to run:

1. apt-get update && sudo apt-get dost-upgrade
2. sudo rpi-update

I've even tweaked the module and blacklist to see what was up.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspistill -v -o image.jpg
raspistill Camera App v1.3.8

Width 2592, Height 1944, quality 85, filename image.jpg
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
Camera component done
Encoder component done
Starting component connection stage
Connecting camera preview port to video render.
Connecting camera stills port to encoder input port
Opening output file image.jpg
Enabling encoder output port
Starting capture 0
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

`sudo raspi-config` will let you ensure you enabled your camera, or use the Menu, Preferences to see if its enabled.  Beyond that the red light doesn't seem to mean anything and it may require a replacement.
I just ordered a 8MP one to see if it works.

I also checked this command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
```

### Update

I got my 8MP camera in, and it worked.  I am starting to think there was something just wrong with my 5MP camera.
Few notes on the behaviors I got myself into.
 - if you do a `sudo mod probe bcm2835-v412` it appears to mount the camera to /dev/video0.  At this point you can no longer use raspistill/vid without getting the ENOSPC error I was getting. 
I had added that to work with motion so I could stream from the web.

I've bounced around with a few projects now and haven't found much joy with the implementation, but at minimum the raspistill commands worked and I did get motion working, however I didn't want mjpeg and still need to sort out if h264 is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Change out all parts of power to pi - obvious statement. With `vcgencmd get_camera` giving `supported=1` and `detected=1`, yet still getting raspistill error, I found a fix after using a better power supply (5V 2.1A) and USB power cable. Surprising since original power worked fine for other pi/camera combos.